# how to delete or replace a word In file directly

Tags: c++, file

In a large file, how to replace the certain word?

Is there is a way to delete a particular `line or word` in file?

EDIT:

My file is quite large.
I cannot load entire file in to buffer and replace the buffer to file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180412/search-and-replace-string-in-txt-file-in-c

Comment: Ordinary files cannot do this unless you rewrite the entire file. Databases use complex file structures and code to accomplish delete or replace.

Answer (score 1):

read each line from the file into a string, then apply std::string's replace (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Comment: I will make changes to string using this... How can i remove the word in file.

Comment: @VinothKumar You need to read, change, and then write your changes. There's no way to remove parts of files.

Comment: Sorry @Debasish Jana I am just new to this... I thought that write in file just insert it in to file instead of replace... Now i am clear

Comment: @molbdnilo Then how to deal with large files? Is there is any alternative

Comment: @VinothKumar One piece (a line or a predetermined size) at a time. You don't need to store the whole file in RAM at the same time.